# Why does this only work sometimes? (UITextView resign first responder question)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, keyboard, uitextview

When a user presses the "SEND"(return) button I want the keyboard to retract and do other stuff like send a message. But it only works SOMETIMES...

Why does this code only work SOMETIMES? I need it to work all the time obviously, but it doesn't.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)inTextView {

    NSString *text = myTextView.text;

    if ([text length] > 0 && [text characterAtIndex:[text length] -1] == '\n') {
        myTextView.text = [text substringToIndex:[text length] -1];
        [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
        [self sendMessage];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only gets called if

```
([text length] > 0 && [text characterAtIndex:[text length] -1] == '\n')
```

is true. Is this always the case? Maybe add an NSLog statement outside and inside the state to see if it is indeed true all of the time.

Comment: assuming myTextView is the text area that has the current focus.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for \n looks bizarre. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

This method is getting passed in a view called inTextView but inside the method you are referring to myTextView and you don't mention where that got set.

I would suggest that you change all the myTextView references to inTextView and see if that resolves the problem as you may be working on a UITextView other than myTextView and seeing your problems because of that.